# How can I improve performance in my application?

Tags: ios, instruments

I'm trying to improve the performance in my iOS application, because there is a page or two that lag and frame drop.
I tried using Time Profiler, and I saw that there is this `commit_prepare` in `QuartzCore`, to my understanding, this is the graphics, like downloading an image.
I do use a lot of images in the application, But I don't really know what to improve, I tried using cache so I won't download the image over and over again.
As far as I know, there is also the image decoding, which should not be on the main thread, so I tried to decode the image and create a `UIImage` in the `URLSession` (that to my knowledge is running on the background thread, please correct me if I'm wrong), and only display the downloaded image on the main thread.
For example, this is my `UIImageView` subclass so download the images.

```
import UIKit

private let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()

class CachedImage: UIImageView {

    private var imageUrlString: String?

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

        imageUrlString = urlString

        //Since the OS is recycling the cells, we set the image to nil so we don't see old image before setting the new one.
        self.image = nil

        //Check if we got the image cached. if so, use it.
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage{
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        //If we don't have the image cached, download it.
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }

            //Cache the downloaded image.
            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: urlString as NSString)

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

But still, the main thread use percentage is super high, like 70-80%.
[image]

I tried looking, and some of this does not show the problematic function name, so I don't know what may cause this.
How can I detect that and improve the performance?

Comment: `commit_prepare` has nothing to do with downloading files, nor does QuartzCore have anything to do with downloading files. The fact that the file happens to be an image does not change anything about downloading it. You are likely looking in the wrong place. Expand the high-impact frames in Instruments (click the right-pointing triangle beside _CFRunLoopDoObservers, for example). You're looking at the part of the stack that just generically says "do the next thing scheduled." Keep expanding till you find your code.

Comment: QuartzCore is responsible for *rendering* things (and eventually placing them on screen). That's independent of the network. If that's substantial and on the main thread, it's possible you're rendering something in the wrong place, but your instruments dump doesn't seem to include what you're describing.

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you. I found few things that needs to be fixed, but how can I fix them? I don't know what I'm doing wrong so I don't know what to fix

Comment: What things did you find that need to be fixed?

Comment: @RobNapier Actually, quite a lot. for example, the profiler says that my homescreenView init function takes a lot of 26ms, or a subclass of UISearchBar to customize the search bar I wrote takes 23ms.